# Binding shows all attributes of model object

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a model object that I inherit from. It's a business object for a webservice implementation. I inherit this object because I need to add INotifyPropertychanged.

It's the same object but with a setter with PropertyChanged.

When I bind the grid to my observablecollection it binds to all the attributes not the ones that I am just interested in (4 attributes).

What could be reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx), than this is the default behavior

To turn it off, set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and define your own `<DataGrid.Columns>`

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
        ...
     <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid>
```